# Elasticsearch: Top k results per keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

We have the following document in elasticsearch.

```
class Query(DocType):
    text = Text(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
    src = Keyword()
```

Now we want top k results for each **src**. How can we achieve this?

Example:- Lets assume we index the following:

```
# src: place_order
Query(text="I want to order food", src="place_order")
Query(text="Take my order", src="place_order")
...

# src: payment
Query(text="How to pay ?", src="payment")
Query(text="Do you accept credit card ?", src="payment")
...
```

Now if the user writes a query ***take my order please along with the credit card details***, and **k=1**, then we should return the following two results

```
[{"text": "Take my order", "src": "place_order", }, 
 {"text": "Do you accept credit card ?", "src": "payment"}
]
```

Here since k=1, we are returning the just one result for each src.

Comment: I understand this is your mapping; may you please also provide few examples of documents and what would be a desired returned result? Thanks.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev I've added the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation which will return top N matching documents per each bucket in aggregation.

For the example in your post the query might look like this:

```
POST queries/query/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "take my order please along with the credit card details"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "src types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "src"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "best hit": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search on the text query restricts the set of documents for the aggregation. `"src types"` aggregation groups all `src` values found in the matched documents, and `"best hit"` selects one most relevant document per bucket (`size` parameter can be changed according to your needs).

The result of the query would be like the following:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1.3862944,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "queries",
        "_type": "query",
        "_id": "VD7QVmABl04oXt2HGbGB",
        "_score": 1.3862944,
        "_source": {
          "text": "Do you accept credit card ?",
          "src": "payment"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "queries",
        "_type": "query",
        "_id": "Uj7PVmABl04oXt2HlLFI",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "text": "Take my order",
          "src": "place_order"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "queries",
        "_type": "query",
        "_id": "UT7PVmABl04oXt2HKLFy",
        "_score": 0.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "text": "I want to order food",
          "src": "place_order"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "src types": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "place_order",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "best hit": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": 0.8630463,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "queries",
                  "_type": "query",
                  "_id": "Uj7PVmABl04oXt2HlLFI",
                  "_score": 0.8630463,
                  "_source": {
                    "text": "Take my order",
                    "src": "place_order"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "payment",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "best hit": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1.3862944,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "queries",
                  "_type": "query",
                  "_id": "VD7QVmABl04oXt2HGbGB",
                  "_score": 1.3862944,
                  "_source": {
                    "text": "Do you accept credit card ?",
                    "src": "payment"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!